# using Tkinter. How could I wrap images so they would not be out of window

Tags: python, tkinter, flexbox

Could you help me please solve this problem? I have a list of images (each image is unique) and I want to display all images in tkinter window (each image has its own button). The problem is if I have more than 5 images, the 6th image is out of window (if I want to see this image I have to resize window → not very optional).
In CSS is this awesome idea of flex-box and wrap, that looks like this:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.element {
  flex: 0 0 200px; /* Adjust the width of each element as needed */
  margin: 10px;
}
```

I need to apply same method in tkinter.
If you know what would solve my problem I would be really glad
here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk


class MyApplication:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tk.Tk()

        # Create a list of image paths
        image_paths = [
            "./pozadia/pozadie1.png",
            "./pozadia/pozadie2.png",
            "./pozadia/pozadie3.png",
            "./pozadia/pozadie4.png",
            "./pozadia/pozadie8.png",
            "./pozadia/pozadie8.png",
            "./pozadia/pozadie8.png",
        ]

        # Create a list of PhotoImage objects
        self.images = [tk.PhotoImage(file=path).subsample(4, 4) for path in image_paths]

        num_images = len(image_paths)

        # Create a container frame to hold the frames with image-button pairs
        container = tk.Frame(self.window)
        container.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        for i in range(num_images):
            # Create a Frame to hold the picture and button
            frame = tk.Frame(container)

            image = self.images[i]

            # Create a Label to hold the picture
            image_label = tk.Label(frame, image=image)
            image_label.pack(side=tk.TOP)  # Place the picture at the top of the frame

            button = tk.Button(frame, text=f"Button {i+1}", command=lambda id=i+1: self.button_click(id))
            button.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)  # Place the button at the bottom of the frame

            frame.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=10, pady=10)  # Place the frame to the left

    def button_click(self, button_id):
        print("Button clicked:", button_id)

    def run(self):
        self.window.mainloop()


app = MyApplication()
app.run()
```

I am expecting that each image with its own button will be visible in window, without resizing window (enable wrapping)

Comment: Put your images in a Text widget, then set it to disabled state.  Let word wrapping do the job for you.

Comment: You can use a `Text` widget with wrap enabled to hold frames with an image and a button in each frame.

Answer (score 1):

You can put those frames with image and button inside in a `Text` widget with `wrap` enabled:

```py
# Create a container to hold the frames with image-button pairs
container = tk.Text(width=40, wrap="word")
container.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

for i in range(num_images):
    # Create a Frame to hold the picture and button
    frame = tk.Frame(container, padx=5, pady=5, bg="white")

    image = self.images[i]

    # Create a Label to hold the picture
    image_label = tk.Label(frame, image=image, bg="white")
    image_label.pack(side=tk.TOP)  # Place the picture at the top of the frame

    button = tk.Button(frame, text=f"Button {i+1}", command=lambda id=i+1: self.button_click(id))
    button.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)  # Place the button at the bottom of the frame

    # put the frame into the text box
    container.window_create("end", window=frame)

container.config(state="disabled", cursor="arrow")
```

Sample result:

[image]